# Display1 No cameras rendering

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was doing a project in unity and till yesterday it was running perfectly fine. Today as soon as I opened my project there pops up a message in the game view saying, '**Display 1 No cameras rendering**'. And moreover my hierarchy window became completely empty. So how do I get back to where I was yesterday ?

Display 1 No cameras rendering.

Comment: The message is because there are no cameras in the active scene, which matches with the empty hierarchy. Did you save your scene? If so, open it.

Comment: Yes hopefully you saved the scene somewhere. I always also recommend version control!